# Can I avoid double forcycle by bsxfun?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I am wondering, if it is possible to use double bsxfun, or something similar. I have this piece of code:

```
N = 5;
prob = [0.1 0.2 0 0.1; 0 0 0.05 0.1; 0.2 0.2 0 0.1];
r = rand(size(prob,1),N);

P = zeros(N, size(prob,1));
csm = cumsum(normP([zeros(size(prob,1),1),prob]),2);

for i = 1:N
 P(i,:) = sum(bsxfun(@ge,r(:,i),csm),2);
end
```

Prob matrix contains rows with elements between 0 and 1, each row is probability distribution (after normalisation done by normP). First row of prob matrix is used to generate first element of vector P (values1,2 or 4), second row for the second element (values 3 or 4), and so on.

```
e.g.: P =

       2     4     2
       4     4     1
       2     4     2
       2     4     4
       2     3     1
```

I have already vectorised generating elements for one vector P, but I need to generate several (N) vectors. There must be way to avoid the for cycle.

In the attachment, there is the normP function. I will be glad for help, thank you.

Michal Roubalik

P.S. Code of normP is here:

```
function nP = normP(P)
%
% Probability matrix normalization to hold sum of rows be equal to one
% i.e. sum(nP,2) = ones(N,1)
%
% No dependencies
srowP = sum(P,2);
good  = srowP>0;
bad   = ~good;
nP    = zeros(size(P));

% good case
if any(good)
    nP(good,:) = bsxfun(@rdivide, P(good,:), srowP(good));
end
% bad case
if any(bad)
    nP(bad,:) = nan(size(P(bad,:)));
end
```

Comment: Before you touch any advanced stuff like `bsxfun`, do the simple optimisations. `cumsum(normP([zeros(size(prob,1),1),prob]),2))` is an expression you evaluate again and again in your loop, pre-compute it outside your loop.

Comment: And replace `nP    = zeros(size(P));` with `nP    = nan(size(P));`, then you can delete the `%bad case`

Comment: thank you, I have changed the code, also I edited code in the question. It is aproximately 30% faster now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to complete vectorization with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) -

```
P = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@ge,permute(r,[1 3 2]),csm),2)).'
```

**Explanation**

1) Push dim-2 of `r` to `dim-3` position bringing in `singleton-dim` at `dim=2`. So, when paired with `csm` for `bsxfun(@ge` operation, we would have a `3D` array as output, whose :

```
dim-1 : r, csm 's dim-1
dim-2 : csm's dim-2
dim-3 : r's dim-2
```

2) The original operation had iterative output with `dim-2` still representing `csm's dim-2` and `sum-reduction` along it. So, in our 3D array output, we need to sum-reduce along `dim-2` as well.

3) Final steps involve `squeeze`-ing and transpose to correspond to the way we are iteratively saving output `P`.